# How can a conditional statement be used in a piped command?

Tags: shell-script, awk, string

The data being processed will follow specific patterns. In this case I'd like to isolate all characters found in the third column and return any characters found after the *"-"* but only if that delimiter is present in the column. Otherwise it should return nothing.

```
eval $A=$(echo $1 | awk -F"." '{print $3}' | cut -d\- -f2-)
```

The first `awk` statement breaks the string into

```
111
222
333-ab3-On21-2
```

The `cut` command prints characters after the first "-".

**string 1** `111.2222.333-ab3-On21-2` returns the desired result:

```
ab3-On21-2
```

**string 2** `111.2222.334` returns an unwanted result:

```
333
```

The `"-"` delimiter is not present in the last section of the string, how could this code be changed to return 0 or "" in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting a "conditional" from, because your statement doesn't have any conditionals in it.  The `awk -F- {print}` isn't doing anything useful; just passing the input through to the output.

However you may be able to do what you want with a `sed` expression, to simplify the whole pipeline:

```
sed -n 's/.*\.[^-]*-\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

The `-n` and the `p` means that it will only print strings that match the expression.

The expression will strip until the last `.` and then strip everything before the first `-`.

So:

```
% echo 111.2222.333-ab3-On21-2 | sed -n 's/.*\.[^-]*-\(.*\)/\1/p'
ab3-On21-2
% echo 111.2222.333 | sed -n 's/.*\.[^-]*-\(.*\)/\1/p'           
%
```

If your input is more complex (eg there may be four `.` delimited fields) then the pattern may need to be a little more clever.

```
sed -n 's/.*\.[^-]*-\([^\.]*\).*/\1/p'
```

eg

```
% echo 111.2222.333-ab3-On21-2.999 | sed -n 's/.*\.[^-]*-\([^\.]*\).*/\1/p'
ab3-On21-2
```

Comment: I wonder whether the second awk was really meant to be `awk '/-/{print}'` and that was the "conditional" inclusion.

Comment: I've edited the question to be clearer. Conditional is based on whether or not a "-" is present in the column following the "." delimiter. If "-" is present cut else print "".

Comment: You write "The second awk breaks down the third columns into columns"... but, no, it doesn't.  The second awk does _nothing_ useful because the `{print}` just prints the input (`$0`), and you're not doing anything to change that.

Comment: My bad that was the intended use, sorry for the confusion, I changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o -P '[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^-]*-\K.*'
```

At first I thought of using positive lookbehind, but it didn't work with non-fixed-length regex. Then, I did a little googling and found out Perl has `\K` token to reset match.

Examples:

```
grep -o -P '[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^-]*-\K.*' <<< 111.222.333-ab3-0n21-2

ab3-0n21-2
```

```
grep -o -P '[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^-]*-\K.*' \
  <<< '128-2sd83--.3 832 @!@!# 323.7 dskj ...-ab3-0n21-2'

ab3-0n21-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut`, with the `-s` (or `--only-delimited`) option:

```
printf '%s\n' '111.2222.333-ab3-On21-2' '111.2222.334' | 
cut -d '.' -f 3 | cut -d '-' -sf 2-
```

Output:

```
ab3-On21-2
```